# Dynamic show fields Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I trying to add some fields to form depending of checkbox. But I have no idea how can I do that. I think Ajax can be useful, but I dont work with Ajax in Symfony2 yet, and if my form build up not in the controller what value I need specify in url: option of Ajax?

Comment: ajax has nothing to do with symfony, its client side. But you are right, dynamically adding fields in a form can be done with ajax. But building form types which can handle dynamically added fields is a whole other story...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite a broad question, but essentially: the Symfony way is to add them to the Form in the Controller by reacting to FormEvents.

[Symfony Docs on Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

One way to achieve what you're after is to submit the form twice - the first time code will react to the checked checkbox and arrange the rest of the form as required, the second time the form will be valid and you can take action.  Details on the above link.  AJAX might help with this, allowing a form submission as soon as you've checked the checkbox.

Although you can create HTML form fields using AJAX, when you submit the form those fields need to exist in the Form object.  You can add them just in time, in the controller, before Symfony tries to bind them.